# EXCEL: How do I return multiple columns using XLOOKUP, when the lookup_value is a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Whenever I try to perform an XLOOKUP using a range for the "lookup_value" and a "return_array" that has multiple columns, Excel will only ever return the first column.

Here's the formula I'm using:

=XLOOKUP(E2:E6,A2:A11,B2:C11)

If the value is found, it ONLY ever returns the XLOOKUP value in column B. If I change the "lookup_value" to one cell instead of a range, it works.

How do I get it to return multiple columns?

I've attached an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOF3W.png) of what happens.

Comment: Try something like `=IFNA(INDEX(B2:C11,XMATCH(E2:E6,A2:A11),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B2:C11))),"")`.

Comment: If I use that formula, it will return me the two columns for E2. I was hoping however I'd be able to use a range, to save having to copy the formula down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does so because you referencing an array. The function then simply returns only a 1st column (just like `TEXTSPLIT()` a.o. would).

To fix this and do this by row, use:

```
=XLOOKUP(E2,A2:A11,B2:C11)
```

If you want to do this in a single go, use:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(B2:C11,XMATCH(E2:E6,A2:A11))
```