Is any way to change XLOOKUP behavior?
From the source data table



Name1
Name2
ID




Wanda
Al
1


Olin
Normand
2


Harriet
Brock
3


Harriet
Brock
16


Wanda
Al
14


Olin
Normand
15



i would like to take each row with the first occurrence of Name1 (E2:G4):

Formulas:
E2 =UNIQUE(A2:A7)
F2 and fill down =XLOOKUP(E2;$A$2:$A$7;$B$2:$C$7)

As we can see, XLOOKUP perfectly works and returns the row from the source range. But it doesn't work similar in a single formula as depicted above for I2. In this case it returns the first column only.
Is any way to enforce it to work in a single formula?
Is any explanation of such XLOOKUP behavior?
P. S. This question is more about XLOOKUP behavior then the solution for this particular usage case. Any guess how XLOOKUP works is welcome. It will help to understand the general approach.

You are retuning values from $A$2:$C$7 in your new formula, while returning $B$2:$C$7 in the old one.

@zipa This is subtly noted. I would like to have three columns in the result. In the first case I need only two columns since the first column is available already.

=CHOOSEROWS(A2:C7,XMATCH(UNIQUE(A2:A7),A2:A7,0))

What exactly is your desired output? E1G:4? What if people share Name1 but not Name2?

@user11222393 Yes, it works!

@Excellor the desired output is every complete row of the source data table where Name1 occurred in the first time.

@Excellor the desired result is to understand how XLOOKUP works.

@JvdV's https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912709/7274479

If you use a single argument xlookup can spill several columns as a result, but if you use larger range or array as lookup value, the formula returns the first column only. You can combine chooserows, xmatch as answered to get your desired result.

If you intend on using XLOOKUP, you need to combine it in REDUCE to keep the ability to spill multiple column results for single values. Each iteration of reduce is the single value input =DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(A2:A7),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,XLOOKUP(y,A2:A7,A2:C7)))),1)

Not a sophisticated but working formula
=LET(nam,UNIQUE(A2:A7),
ca,VLOOKUP(nam,A2:C7,2,FALSE),
cb,VLOOKUP(nam,A2:C7,3,FALSE),
HSTACK(nam,ca,cb))

VLOOKUP can be changed to XLOOKUP if needed.
Ref. to your comment:
=LET(nam,UNIQUE(A2:A7),
ca,MATCH(nam,A2:A7,0),
cb,CHOOSEROWS(B2:C7,ca),
HSTACK(nam,cb))


Yes, it works. But it's the "manual" solution which requires to get every column separately.

Your question was about returning the row in one formula. This is it.

The question is to return complete rows but not compose them. Consider this a clarification to the question.

Agree, this is what SO is about.
